# Can two Powered Up train motors be plugged into one hub

Tags: trains, motor, powered-up

I have set #60198 and it comes with one Powered Up motor. I'm hauling many many cars and one motor isn't enough any more. I see there is a slot for "B" on the hub. Is it possible to plug in another train motor into B and have the train be powered by 2 motors?

Does it even help? Not sure if a second motor would just split the power between the two motors if it worked, or does it draw 2x the battery from the hub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach second train motor to B output. However it will be controlled independently from motor attached to output A. So you would need to control speed for each motor separately.

Speaking of traction. The key thing here is your train weight. You might consider putting another full battery box (unpowered) into train just to increase weight and get more friction between wheels and the track.

Comment: Another thing to consider is that LEGO train motors are not precisely calibrated to run at any particular speed (or at least used not to be), so two motors given the same amount of power might run at slightly different speeds. I have seen trains with several locomotives, each with their own PF motor, that seperated after a short time.

Comment: I've seen this with 9V trains. However PF2 trains seem to be running fine - tested during two day event without uncoupling. We even had a case of one motor power loss on one end and still had all train parts together. I'm thinking train motor-axle-wheel combination might cause additional friction between these pieces if not adjusted correctly.

Comment: Can you guys take a look at the link? is this the right part? it says `Powered up` but it also says `9v`. I know `9v` is the old system right? https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=167303#T=S&C=11&O={%22color%22:11,%22loc%22:%22US%22,%22iconly%22:0}

Comment: Correct, that's the latest train motor for PowerUp (aka Power Functions 2.0) currently available.

Comment: If you know any programming, there are third party Boost/PoweredUp libraries you can use to control the train from a bluetooth-enabled computer. You can then write a program that takes input from the remote and powers both motors simultaneously.

Comment: The other motor came and it worked like a charm. It's pulling about 12 cars with no sweat. my 3 year old son doesn't care, but I'm real happy.